# get metrics for google cloud pubsub

Tags: publish-subscribe, metrics, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using google cloud pubsub and I want to know about how to get number of outstanding, delivered and undelivered messages in pubsub. Is there any available api provided by google pubsub for this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look at [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/). In particular, there are [metrics for Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#gcp-pubsub), including subscription/num_undelivered_messages and subscription/num_outstanding_messages. You can also access graphs of these properties in [Stackdriver](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/).

Comment: I have looked at the docs and they are unfortunately confusing to me. Can you provide what the command would look like via the REST API?

Comment: @Tim have you found a way to get num_undelivered_messages via API?